# Trying to use cmd via c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to use a `cmd` command prompt that works just fine when I use it in a normal cmd window via `Windows --> Start --> cmd`

My code looks like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Rapid-I\RapidMiner5\scripts\rapidminer.bat" -f      
"C:\Users\user\.RapidMiner5\repositories\Local Repository\test.rmp"
```

That works just fine.

The problem is when I am trying to write this code in C# by opening a `cmd` window via C#

This is the c# code

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c \"C:\\Program Files\\Rapid-I\\RapidMiner5\\scripts\\rapidminer.bat\" -f \"C:\\Users\\user\\.RapidMiner5\\repositories\\Local Repository\\test.rmp\"");
```

You can see I quoted the same way like the code that work in the regular cmd

But I am getting a `can't recognize program files`.

Comment: `ProgramFiles`...?  Change to `Program Files`

Comment: hi i just edit my comment that wasnt the problom
this was my mistake when copy the code to the web

Comment: Escaping quotes in cmd line via C# is a big pain in the rear.  If I recall, sometimes you need to escape the double quotes with a "double double quote" (two quotes in a row).  For ease, switch to verbatim:  `@"C:\Program Files\...".` and concat strings when u need a double quote literal.

Comment: i don't really understand you so much

Comment: Try either `"C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Rapid-I\\RapidMiner5\\scripts\\rapidminer.bat"` or, for ease of reading, `@"C:\""Program Files""\Rapid-I\RapidMiner5\scripts\rapidminer.bat"`. Because `Program Files` contains whitespace but is part of the same argument, it needs to be surrounded by quotes. The same also applies to `Local Repository`  in your second path.

Comment: sory but stil dosent work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string fullPath = @"C:\Program Files\Rapid-I\RapidMiner5\scripts\rapidminer.bat";
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
p.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
p.Arguments = @"/c -f ""C:\Users\user\.RapidMiner5\repositories\Local Repository\test.rmp""";
Process.Start(p);
```

I modified my original code to add arguments to your process.

One last thing you could try is putting your original command into a batch file and calling the batch file from your **ProcessStartInfo** object like so:

C#:

```
string fullPath = @"C:\Program Files\Rapid-I\RapidMiner5\scripts\run.bat";
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
p.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
Process.Start(p);
```

Comment: hi thank you' but its stil getting a "c:/ program is not reconize"

Comment: I modified my code to set the working directory and file name on the process.

Comment: theres progras
now the cmd start the file - @"C:\Program Files\Rapid-I\RapidMiner5\scripts\rapidminer.bat"

but still the other line dosent work - "-f C:\Users\user\.RapidMiner5\repositories\Local Repository\test.rmp"

Comment: that might be because of the space in "program files" and in "local repository". Try wrapping your string in ' characters like this: `@"'C:\Program Files\whatever'"` and `@"-f 'C:\whatever else\'"`

Comment: Thank you Vlad. I forgot to wrap that line with `@`. The code has been fixed now.

Comment: so Frustrating 
still that solution oparte the .bat file
but dosnt start the process " test.rmp"
please help! :(

Comment: camron dosent the all path should be in the argument and not onli the f and test.remp?

Comment: The `-f` is a flag and unless that second path is a process, it is passed as an argument to the batch file. If it is a process, you can run both processes separately, one after the other.

Comment: mm...both process must come toghetr at least i think so

the test.ramp must work troghe batch file

any way your solution only opend the batch file
mybe there is another way?

Comment: The problem seems to be the way we write the argument   is there another way to write it?

Comment: See my updated code in my answer. I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Hi camron couple of seconds before reading your updated I did what you suggested and it work just fine     recommend to every one if your using c# and trying to operate other programs just put it in a batch file and lunch the file from c #      thanks camron saved me a lot of headache

Comment: If you could, please mark this answer as the correct answer. Thanks!